# Launching postgres fixture with pytest fails due to LC_ALL cannot change locale error

Tags: python, postgresql, locale

I have been scratching my head for few hours as I can't figure how to debug the following problem.

#### Context

I am using pytest and pytest-postgresql on a project, to learn TDD.

pytest-postgres enables me to use a fixture that implements a postgresql database in the /tmp directory on a socket.

This used to work well, and is explained in:

- the docs https://pypi.org/project/pytest-postgresql/
- this article: 
  https://medium.com/@geoffreykoh/fun-with-fixtures-for-database-applications-8253eaf1a6d.

#### The problem

A sample test which use that fixture produces the following error:

```
>               raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
                                         output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
E               subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/pg_ctl',
 'initdb', '--pgdata', '/tmp/postgresqldata.12836',
 '-o', '--username=postgres --auth=trust']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:512: CalledProcessError
/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:512: CalledProcessError
---------------------------- Captured stderr setup -----------------------------
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
pg_ctl: database system initialization failed
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR tests/adapters/test_orm.py::test_sample - subprocess.CalledProcessError...
=============================== 1 error in 0.11s ===============================
```

#### What I have tried

- resetting locale
- reinstall postgres
- reinstall pytest-postgres
- reinstall psycopg2-binary

I also launched a similar command directly from the shell

It does not trigger such an error:

```
(myproject) [john@linuxbox ~/myproject]$ initdb --pgdata /tmp/postgresqldata.123450 --username=postgres --auth=trust 

The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "john". 
This user must also own the server process. 
The database cluster will be initialized with locales 
  COLLATE:  fr_FR.UTF-8 
  CTYPE:    fr_FR.UTF-8 
  MESSAGES: en_US.UTF-8 
  MONETARY: fr_FR.UTF-8 
  NUMERIC:  fr_FR.UTF-8 
  TIME:     fr_FR.UTF-8 
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8". 
The default text search configuration will be set to "french". 
Data page checksums are disabled. 
creating directory /tmp/postgresqldata.123450 ... ok 
creating subdirectories ... ok 
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix 
selecting default max_connections ... 100 
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB 
selecting default time zone ... Europe/Paris 
creating configuration files ... ok 
running bootstrap script ... ok 
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok 
syncing data to disk ... ok 
Success. You can now start the database server using: 
    pg_ctl -D /tmp/postgresqldata.123450 -l logfile start
```

#### Questions:

- Are the two commands below equivalent ?

*from pytest*:

```
Command '['/usr/bin/pg_ctl', 'initdb', '--pgdata', '/tmp/postgresqldata.12836',
 '-o', '--username=postgres --auth=trust']'
```

*from the shell*:

```
initdb --pgdata /tmp/postgresqldata.123450 --username=postgres --auth=trust
```

- any idea of where should I look next to solve this ?

Thanks!

#### Edit 1

Thanks a lot for your comments.

output of `$ locale -a`

```
C 
en_US.utf8 
fr_FR.utf8 
POSIX
```

pytest-postgresql is on 2.5.1:

```
(myproject) [john@linuxbox ~/myproject]$ cat Pipfile.lock | grep pytest-postgresql -A 6 
        "pytest-postgresql": { 
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:e2a998c85cd7e917c593292182e523d620018887fadde733c932a70c3825b8bd" 
            ], 
            "index": "pypi", 
            "version": "==2.5.1" 
        },
```

I'm on Archlinux and use postgres 12.4.

#### Edit 2

I think I found the reason, I could reproduce the error from the shell.

following the archwiki, I did this:

```
[postgres@linuxbox ~]$ initdb --locale=C.UTF-8 -E UTF-8 -D /var/lib/postgres/data 
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres". 
This user must also own the server process. 
initdb: invalid locale name "C.UTF-8"
```

It seems C.UTF-8 is Debian specific, hence the error on Archlinux.

This issue seems closely related:
https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-postgresql/issues/338

Comment: The changelog for the most recent version of pytest-postgresql (2.5.1) makes a reference to LC_* environment variables, and was released only a few days ago. Definitely check with the most recent version if you're not already on it.

Comment: Make sure the C.UTF-8 locale is installed in your system (run the locale command  - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue).